# What is the syntax for deleting/releasing Twilio phone numbers in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twilio

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to delete a Twilio phone number via the API.

Here's my code:

```
  var twilioSID = user.numberSID; // PN946a0603c974be563c5916f865be4d0b
  var accountSid = '{removed}';
  var authToken = '{removed}';
  var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

  client.incomingPhoneNumbers(twilioSID).delete(function(err, deleted) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Deleted from Twilio');
    }
  });
```

Here is the error I'm getting in the console:

```
  { 
     status: 404,
     message: 'The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/{removed}/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN946a0603c974be563c5916f865be4d0b.json was not found',
     code: 20404,
     moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404' 
  }
```

The Twilio API doesn't have hardly any documentation for deleting numbers either. Any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to delete a media instance. A call through the API to list the media instances works, and I can get values for individual instances, but trying to call delete on them returns 404.

Answer (score 2):

@parkeragee Your solution is working

```
client.incomingPhoneNumbers(poneNumberSID).delete(function(err, deleted) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Deleted from Twilio');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

They changed it from delete to remove in their node js module.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer. Do you have a source for this (ideally official documentation), and could you show some code that demonstrates it?

Comment: @FabioTurati The docs don't seem to be updated but I did find in the source code that the function is called `remove`.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, the function to remove Twilio phone numbers via the API is called `remove`. If you try to use `delete`, you should receive the following error:

> client.incomingPhoneNumbers(...).delete is not a function

I wasn't able to find any reference in the Twilio API docs; found this by [reading the source, Luke](https://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/).

Here's an example invoking `remove`:

```
client.incomingPhoneNumbers(sid).remove()
.then(function(deleted) {
    // Success
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to their [REST API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-delete), you can send an HTTP DELETE request to a url like `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers/{IncomingPhoneNumberSid}`. So the URL in the error message looks almost right, except for the `.json` on the end. Either way it looks like a bug in their code if the phone number is in fact still attached to your account.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was overwriting my production phone nuber `numberSID` variable with my test phone number. So the `user.numberSID;` that I was assigning to a variable was for the Twilio test phone numbers. So, when it was searching for that numberSID, it returned a 404.